# Character Encoding? Site Migration to new Server after Upload of UI displaying full page of diamonds with ? marks inside

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, drupal-7

So I have just completed a migration to a new server, after restoring the mysql dump the site was working fine, but as soon as I uploaded the front end I was faced with this '��}�v�8����9���HސI���#e����Mb' etc for the whole site. Have searched the web but there seems to be nothing relating to my problem. My new server is running CentOS with a LAMP stack and all the usuals. The site is Drupal 7.something

Any help or suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

(Too long for a comment.)

'Plüg' sounds German, but the sample text is not a simple transcoding of German text.  What was the intended text?  What language was the text in?  One character is Maldivian, but the rest does not fit.

The sample output makes it sound like you have two errors, so let's do some debugging...

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...
```

to display some cell that should have non-English text in it.  From that, we might be able to decide whether the text was damaged upon input, or is damaged coming back out.

This question *may* be a duplicate of [utf8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).  And/or you may need `utf8mb4`.

Comment: Correct on the surname, good call! Hahaha, I did manage to sort it out though, text was all english by the way. Will post my fix here later today!

Comment: It's really hard to turn English text into black diamonds!  I'll be interested to hear what the cause was.  ('Plüg' -- a simple web search led to hints of German.  Plus, `ü` is mostly found in German.)